# Webservices vs Microservices

Tags: java, web-services, soa, microservices

In our org , we have soap & rest based services that have focused set of responsibilities. For instance , there is customer service for managing customer info , account service for managing account info etc. Is there any advantage of making them microservices? If it has to be converted to a microservice , what typically has to be done?

When I read about microservices , it is primarily being compared with monolithic apps. But in all the large companies that I have worked over the past 5-6 yrs , I have always seen things implemented as webservices. I don't see many examples of why microservice is advantageous over rest based service.

Comment: "webservice" and "microservice" aren't mutually exclusive terms, nor do they have strict, objective definitions. It's possible that all of your web services already are microservices by many people's definitions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are your web services individually deployable? Individually scalable? Individually monitored?

Microservices are just more granular (and decoupled) varieties of the web services most places have to provide a little more control on the Ops side of the world. Is that useful for you? Maybe. Maybe not. Different solutions have different needs, and if your scaling needs don't vary in their shape or magnitude, it might provide little benefit.

Comment: Thank you , this is useful. The traditional webservices that we deploy are deployed in our own infrastructure. Unless we build out new VMs etc they cannot be automatically scaled. These services are dependent on other services / data stores. These transactions can be monitored independently using splunk and I assume health check can be performed using appd etc. We also have microservices deployed - as you mentioned these can individually scale out since we have deployed in a cloud infrastructure

Answer (score 5):

Martin Fowler defines Microservices as a subset of Service Oriented Architecture (SOA). It sounds like this is what you have potentially.

With the disclaimer that there isn't a commonly accepted single definition, a Web services is not the only form it could take. Communication could be over various protocols and be event oriented also.

I also believe that there's an engineering culture required to be successful with a Microservices architecture.